Cramer-Rao bound for linear combination
I'm a bit uncertain about Creamer-Rao bound for the linear combination of estimators.
We know that for unbiased estimator $\hat{\theta}$ of some parameter of distribution which satisfies conditions of regularity there holds CRB: $$ var(\hat{\theta}) \geqslant \frac{1}{I(\theta)}$$
where $I(\theta)$ is Fisher information.
Suppose we have two independent estimators $\hat{\theta}_{1}~,~\hat{\theta}_{2}$ of the same parameter. For each of them we have CRB:
$$ var(\hat{\theta}_{1}) \geqslant \frac{1}{I(\theta)} \\ 
var(\hat{\theta}_{2}) \geqslant \frac{1}{I(\theta)}$$
And $$var(\frac{\hat{\theta}_{1} + \hat{\theta}_{2}}{2}) = \frac{1}{4}(var(\hat{\theta}_{1})+ var(\hat{\theta}_{2})) \geqslant 0.25 \cdot \frac{2}{I(\theta)} = \frac{1}{2I(\theta)}  $$
(simply added two previous inequalities)
However, $\frac{\hat{\theta}_{1} + \hat{\theta}_{2}}{2}$ is also unbiased and CRB should be held for it the same way as for separate estimators
$$var(\frac{\hat{\theta}_{1} + \hat{\theta}_{2}}{2}) \geqslant \frac{1}{I(\theta)}$$
What part of these derivations is wrong? I don't understand what to treat as the lower bound of variance for linear combination of unbiased estimators.

The misunderstanding is to think that   the variance of the combined estimator to be bounded below by $\frac{1}{I(\theta)}$, just like the one estimator:
$$
\operatorname{var}(\hat{\theta}_{\text{avg}}) \geq \frac{1}{I(\theta)}.
$$
Where
$$
\hat{\theta}_{\text{avg}} = \frac{\hat{\theta}_1 + \hat{\theta}_2}{2}.
$$
However, this is missing  the fact that the combined estimator benefits from twice the amount of information. Since Fisher information measures the amount of information an estimator provides about the parameter, combining two independent estimators  doubles the information. Therefore, the correct lower bound is:
$$
\operatorname{var}(\hat{\theta}_{\text{avg}}) \geq \frac{1}{2I(\theta)}.
$$

But Fisher information depends only on distribution, isnt't it? It's defined as an expectation of squared derivative of log-likelihood function

@Furdzik Zbignew 's answer is great. I'm just trying to give another angle.
You are missing some key properties of Fisher information.

Fisher information is additive.

If you have two independent pieces of information $X$ and $Y$ about some parameter $\theta$, then the total information $I_{X,Y}(\theta)$ is the sum $I_X(\theta) + I_Y(\theta)$.
the proof is immediate given the definition, but it takes a few lines


In an IID model, Fisher information scales linearly with the number of datapoints $n$.

this is an immediate consequence of the additivity
$I_{X_1 \dots X_n}(\theta) = n I_X(\theta)$
again, the proof is immediate
when we look at the scaling of the variance with $n$, we find the usual decrease of the variance as $1/\sqrt n$



In view of these two facts, your observation is not surprising. If we have two independent estimators, then we have two separate datasets. Any estimator derived from both, like your addition, has its variance bounded by the total Fisher information from the two data sources
